# Sudo is not working

Tags: sudo

My sudo is not working. How to fix? I am using 13.04.

I searched through google over an hour and haven't found anything effective.

```
sudo -i
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

Comment: what happens when you type `sudo -i`

Comment: when did this happen? Is this a fresh install?

Comment: It happened today. I am running it alongside windows 7

Comment: If it's a fresh install install it again. Might be the fastest and cleanest way...

Comment: We need more information to help you.  If its a new install or you have everything backed up so would not lose anything by reinstalling.  I'd reinstall probably the quickest solution.  If not then can you edit the question to let us know what if any changes you made prior to it going wrong.  Also include the output of `id` and details of any warning messages or errors you have seen.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sudo` doesn't have the `setuid` flag. To solve this, run the following command in terminal:

```
pkexec chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?                              chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/bin/sudo’: Operation not permitted

Comment: @user197109 I just edited my answer. Try now.

Comment: You can run this command from a LiveCD that actually has a working `sudo` command.  Just be sure to mount the installed system and `chmod` its `sudo` command.